# Solving a symbolic, nonlinear equation in Matlab/Octave

Tags: matlab, octave, symbolic-math

I'm trying to solve the following steady-state equation for x:

```
0 = -C + 2*C0*(1-exp(-k*A*x*phi))
```

I've defined all variables as **syms**, but can't figure out how to solve the equation for x.  Since all other variables are known, I've tried substituting them in:

```
f = -C + 2*C0*(1-exp(-k*A*x*phi))
subs(f, [C 20], [C0 11], [k .015], [A .031], [phi .01])
```

But this also doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to replace symbolic variables with values using [`subs`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) is to use the *three* input variant. The first is the symbolic expression, [the second](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html#inputarg_old) is an array of symbolic variables to replace, and [the third](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html#inputarg_new) is an array of things that you want to replace each variable in the second input with.

```
syms C C0 k A x phi

f = -C + 2*C0*(1-exp(-k*A*x*phi));

% Substitute in values that are known
newf = subs(f, [C, C0, k, A, phi], [20, 11, 0.015, 0.031, 0.01]);
%   2 - 22*exp(-(93*x)/20000000)

% Solve the resulting symbolic expression for x
result = solve(newf == 0, x)
%   (20000000*log(11))/93

% And if you need a numeric (rather than symbolic) result
double(result)
%   5.1568e+05
```

Comment: Thank you!  This may just be too much for Octave, which outputs `result = {}(0x0)`.

Comment: @Steve_F Updated with a version that works with octave as well. You have to explicitly state that you want the value of `x` when `newf == 0` (this is implied in MATLAB)

Comment: I would also point out that `solve()` has no problem solving the equation for `x` even without substituting in the numerical values. simply typing `anotherresult = solve(f == 0, x)` you should get the resulting formula